# How to make my social icon stop at the top of footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer, sticky

I am trying to stop a social icon from scrolling when it gets to the top of the footer. You can see the [example here](http://www.f316.ng/company/bhm).

It is a Wordpress site. The layout page is done with Visual Composer.

Comment: You will need to show what you've tried: the css or other code you're using. Also, try not to rely on links for showing what you mean, since they are inherently unstable.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS you may want to change the positioning to:

```
/* make social icon sticky to a position */

.myIcon {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Hello, try to make the CSS code indent with 4 whitespaces so that it will turn into a code block to improve readiness. Thank you!

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the feedback, was wondering on how to display the code. I will keep this in mind in future posts.

Comment: @David After changing the position to fixed, it is no longer scrolling, it it now static at a position.     i want it to scroll from the top and stop at the top of the footer.